# How to prove this problem about lebesgue measure?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let E⊆R and  have outer measure.Show that there is an Fσ set F and a Gδ set G Such that F⊆E⊆G and m*(F)＝m*(E)=m*（G）.
I can prove there is G Such that E⊆G and m*(E)=m*(G) by definition of outer measure to get ∪Iₙ and E⊆∪Iₙ, Such that m*(∪Iₙ) <m*(E)+1/n , ∪Iₙ is open take intersection of ∪Iₙ we get G but I can't find closed set to do it.

Comment: Maybe the fact that the complement of a measurable set is also measurable might help?

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math Thank you.

Comment: But E  isn't a measurable set

Comment: Sorry ,but i don't kown use MathJax by   phone .I haven't computer